# Customize HTML search response of Laravel Backpack for Datatables

Tags: php, html, laravel, datatables, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to customize the HTML returned to my Datatable by the `/search` route of a given model in Laravel Backpack but couldn't find where are the files to do this.

I know the content itself is taken from the columns blade files. But I would like to customize the content of the entire row, for example, and not only one single column.

The image illustrates what I want. The red square is what I can change, which is the content of the blade files of my columns. The green square is what I don't know where is located, the content of the entire row (`<tr>`) and wrapper columns (`<td>`).

[image: Explanatory image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to change for the whole row?

Comment: Custom classes or attributes based on the result, things like that.

Comment: See example for [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) option, use that to add classes or attributes based on data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows are loaded in `datatables_logic.blade.php`, using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). You can customize this file in your project by placing a file with the same name in your `resources/views/backpack/crud/inc/datatables_logic.blade.php`.

Hope it helps!